# Portions of my mesh seem to be locked in place and can't be moved, rotated or scaled. How do I fix this?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

So I've been making a human model in blender from scratch. While I was working on the hands, I've suddenly been unable to move, rotate or scale the rest of the mesh. I've seen suggestions that the Transform options need to be unchecked, which has been the case. I'm having trouble finding any other potential solutions, since my issue only cause a majority of my mesh to be unmovable. I am able to move the object as a whole around in object mode, but that's it. An example of this is when I go into edit mode and select the entire mesh and try to move it around. Only the unfixed portion of the hand moves, everything else is stationary. I can't sculpt on those fixed portions either. None of this was an issue a couple days ago when I modeling the rest of the body, but now it's suddenly a problem.

I appreciate any help I can get to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out what the problem was. I noticed that when I selected the faces or edges of the 'fixed' portion of my mesh, the transform panel stated that nothing was selected. Eventually I tried unhiding the mesh, which seemed to fix the issue and allowed me to manipulate the rest of the mesh again. Normally when you hide portions of the mesh, they don't appear visually on the screen, so I had not expected that to be the solution when the entire mesh was visible. Rehiding a portion of the mesh properly hides those faces so I have no idea why I could see them in the first place.